# Several buttons for different sound but one button for play

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I need to have several buttons where each button just determines what sound is to play when it is pressed, and one another play button that will play that determined sound. Is it possible in Flash AS3. 
Anyone have an idea?

Comment: I feel like it is a basic logic you are asking here and I hope the language has the capability to do your requirement. Have searched on the web and tried this before posting here?

Comment: Yes it is possible, what have you tried?

Comment: Yes, but I have not found nothing that help me make this. I know how to code button to play sound, stop, pause etc.  but I can`t figure out how to play sound with one same button but with several other buttons to change what sound is to be played that is from library.

Comment: I am not that skilled in as3 so I need help please!

Comment: One of solutions that I tried is to make second frame with different code that makes button play another sound. This is not sophisticated solution but I cannot figureout another..

Comment: Make a variable that will hold a value that determines what sound to play. Make your 'change sound' buttons set the value of the variable. Make your play button play whatever sound is set in that variable, not hard coded to any specific sound.